# TypeError: check_is_fitted() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attributes'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run the code given by the official tutorial. However, I'm getting error

> TypeError: check_is_fitted() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attributes'

```py
from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import check_estimator
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_X_y, check_array, check_is_fitted
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances


class TemplateClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, demo_param='demo'):
        self.demo_param = demo_param

    def fit(self, X, y):

        # Check that X and y have correct shape
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
        # Store the classes seen during fit
        self.classes_ = unique_labels(y)

        self.X_ = X
        self.y_ = y
        # Return the classifier
        return self

    def predict(self, X):

        # Check is fit had been called
        check_is_fitted(self)

        # Input validation
        X = check_array(X)

        closest = np.argmin(euclidean_distances(X, self.X_), axis=1)
        return self.y_[closest]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_estimator(TemplateClassifier)
```

Comment: it seams like a bug in the docs for reference https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html

Comment: I think your scikit-learn version is not updated. With the latest version 0.23, the code is running fine in my machine.

Comment: Thanks, My version was 0.21, I solve the problem by upgrading the version.

Comment: The mean of function check_is_fitted() is check attributes.
It will be like check_is_fitted(self, ['classes_','X_']). Where attributes classes_ and X_ will exists and have values

Answer (score 0):

Update scikit-learn to 0.23 works fine to me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30685837)